# Start Grunt watch at phpStorm startup

Tags: gruntjs, phpstorm

Is it possible to automatically start a Grunt watch task when phpStorm opens the project?

I have setup Grunt and added the Grunt tool window as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/grunt-tool-window.html). It is now easy to start my watch from that Grunt tool window, but it doesn't happen automatically when I start phpStorm. I would like to eliminate that final click. For as far as I can find this is not possible though asked for [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11818)

Comment: Not currently possible. If it would be that ticket would be closed/resolved by now.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible from setting / startup tasks

[image: Settings screen]